# CASE WHEN Statement referencing two different Columns

Tags: sql

As you can see in the screenshot below, there are multiple account numbers that have either a "successful" or "fail" outcome. Some account numbers have multiple entries like account_number "413655". For accounts like "413655", where one outcome is Success, and the other outcome is fail, I want to create a new column that shows "success" for both entries. Only accounts that have all fail outcomes should display "fail" in this new column "Distinct_count". The rest should display "success".

SCREENSHOT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQZmY.jpg

Please find my query below.(I have bolded the part that needs to be edited)

```
-- @WbResult v_tcci_collection_activity_fact
SELECT date_dim_id,
B.user_key,
B.product_type,
B.dealer_nbr,
(CASE B.make
WHEN 'TOYOTA' THEN 'TOYOTA'
WHEN 'SUBARU' THEN 'SUBARU'
WHEN 'LEXUS' THEN 'LEXUS'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END),
C.dealer_name,
C.zone,
activity_date,
activity_time,
activity_code,

 

(CASE WHEN len(b.loan_nbr) > 3 
THEN b.loan_nbr
ELSE b.lease_nbr END)
AS account_number,

 

(CASE WHEN activity_code IN ('SHPS','SBPS','SOPS','SHCS','SBCS') THEN 'Successful'
ELSE 'Fail' END)
AS outcome,


**(CASE WHEN outcome = 'Successful' AND outcome = 'Fail' OR outcome = 'Successful' THEN 'Successful'
ELSE 'Fail' END)
AS distinct_count** 



 

FROM dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_collection_activity_fact A
left join dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_collection_account_dim B
on A.collection_account_dim_id = B.collection_account_dim_id
left join dm_business_ops_tcci.v_tcci_dealer_dim C
on A.dealer_dim_id = C.dealer_dim_id
where activity_code IN ('SBCS','SOPF','SBPS','SOPS','SHPF','SHPS','SBCF','SBPF','SHCF','SHCS')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to parse through the whole query in your example, but in your scenario a [Windowing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) is a good way to achieve this scenario.

Your query won't work as it's only doing things row-by-row, so you need to be able to take in the details from the other row to make it happen.

In your case you want to use a Windowing Function like the following (simplified from your specific example):

```
MAX(outcome) OVER (PARTITION BY account_number) AS outcome_overall
```

Here I am being a little cheap and nothing that `Successful` comes after `Fail` in the dictionary to utilize `MAX`. But with this, `outcome_overall` is calculated by:

1. Partitioning the dataset into separate chunks based on `account_number`.
2. Within each partition, it finds the `MAX(outcome)`.
3. `outcome_overall` is that value from #2, repeated for each row in that partition.

Example data and what `outcome_overall` would be:

| `account_number` | `outcome` | `outcome_overall` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Successful | Successful |
| A1 | Fail | Successful |
| A2 | Fail | Fail |
| A2 | Fail | Fail |
| A3 | Successful | Successful |
| A4 | Fail | Fail |